# named url not working in django 1.5 and python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I'm developing my own blog. Everything was good. I tried prepare it for deployment which was not successful. Now I undo all changes, but named url not working now (they were worked perfectly before):
error:

> Reverse for ''main_page'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', main_page, name='main_page'),
  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.blogurls')),
  url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
)
```

main page view:

```
def main_page(request):
  object_list = Article.objects.all()
  return render_to_response('blog/main_page.html', {'Latest': object_list}
```

named url used in:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'main_page' %}">home</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `{% url 'main_page' %}` with `{% url main_page %}`.

Quote from django 1.5 [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/):

> One deprecated feature worth noting is the shift to “new-style” url
>   tag. Prior to Django 1.3, syntax like {% url myview %} was interpreted
>   incorrectly (Django considered "myview" to be a literal name of a
>   view, not a template variable named myview). Django 1.3 and above
>   introduced the {% load url from future %} syntax to bring in the
>   corrected behavior where myview was seen as a variable.
>
> The upshot of this is that if you are not using {% load url from
>   future %} in your templates, you’ll need to change tags like {% url
>   myview %} to {% url "myview" %}. If you were using {% load url from
>   future %} you can simply remove that line under Django 1.5

Comment: it worked. but I don't remember any changes in template. thanx

Comment: Do you have `{% load url from future %}` in your templates?

Comment: No!what url from future does?

Comment: Just wondering, it was just a helpful line, that allowed to use `{% url myview %}` syntax in django 1.3 and 1.4.